# Decrease available inventory item on Cognito Form, removing it when zero

Tags: cognito-forms

I want to limit inventory quantities on a sales form, so that it can start at say 100 and count backwards as applicants submit orders and then shut down that particular option when it reaches 0.

Is this possible with Cognito?

Answer (score 3):

You can limit selections in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) by assigning [quantity limits](https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/quantity-limits) to your choice fields.  Simply do the following:

1. Select **Limit Quantities** under *Choice Options*
2. Enter quantities for each choice, or leave blank for unlimited
3. Set the **Quantity Exceeded Error Message** to *Sold out!*

You can learn more about quantity limits in our [help documentation](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/18/building-forms/limiting-quantities)!

[image: limit quantities for choice field in Cognito Forms]